# Grand Total adds Tax when Products already include Taxes

Tags: magento2, tax

Magento 2.3.4 / PHP 7.3

I've set my website tax rules in the following way:

- Product prices in backoffice include Tax
- Shipping prices also include tax

These are the TAX settings:

[image]

This is the product price in BO:

[image]

This means that the price is 5€ and I said in tax calculation that prices already include tax. But in frontend I see that the grand total adds the taxes (Grand Total should be 14.95, but it's 14.95 + 21% tax). What am I doing wrong? Why is it adding taxes when I said in tax calculation settings that prices already have taxes included?

[image]

Comment: Is the selected scope (default / store / website) for the tax configuration the same as the checkout? Is the selected scope for the product the same as the checkout?

Comment: Hi, yes it is (I have only one store / store view and no changes are done in configuration at store view level).

Answer (score 3):

Well, I finally found that the issue was related to the Shipping Origin not set correctly.

After setting the shipping origin (Stores » Configuration » Sale » Shipping Settings) to the same location as my store, taxes were calculated correctly.